# Boto3 Copy_Object failing on size > 5GB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have the following function

```py
async def _s3_copy_object(self, s3_source, s3_destination):
        source_bucket, source_key = get_s3_bucket_and_key(s3_source)
        destination_bucket, destination_key = get_s3_bucket_and_key(s3_destination)
    
        print("copying object: {} to {}".format(s3_source, s3_destination))
        source = {'Bucket': source_bucket, 'Key': source_key}
        await self._async_s3.copy_object(CopySource=source,
                                         Bucket=destination_bucket, Key=destination_key,
                                         ServerSideEncryption='AES256',
                                         MetadataDirective='COPY',
                                         TaggingDirective='COPY')
```

This works great if the file is under 5gb, but fails if the object is over 5gb.

I get the following error:

> An error occurred (InvalidRequest) when calling the CopyObject operation: The specified copy source is larger than the maximum allowable size for a copy source: 5368709120: 1313

Is there a work around for this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to use the boto3 [`copy`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy) method instead of `copy_object`. It will perform the multi-part upload that is required when copying objects greater than 5GB. It will also handle the threading for you.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using Multipart uploads.In a single operation, maximum allowed size is 5GB

[Multi-part upload](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadingObjects.html)

Answer (score 0):

import subprocess

command="aws s3 mv  "

subprocess.call(command,shell=True)

CLI automatically performs multipart upload for you. You may add any parameters that you need in the command.