# Copy s3 files to a new bucket when updated - fails with large files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've found some code (below) which copies files to a new bucket as soon as they are updated in another. It works fine for smaller files, however ones of 5GB are not being copied, is there anything in the code which might need to be changed?

```py
import boto3
import time, urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error
import json
"""Code snippet for copying the objects from AWS source S3 bucket to target S3 bucket as soon as objects uploaded on source S3 bucket
@author: Prabhakar G
"""
print ("*"*80)
print ("Initializing..")
print ("*"*80)

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    source_bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    object_key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])
    target_bucket = 'new-backups-keep'
    copy_source = {'Bucket': source_bucket, 'Key': object_key}
    print ("Source bucket : ", source_bucket)
    print ("Target bucket : ", target_bucket)
    print ("Log Stream name: ", context.log_stream_name)
    print ("Log Group name: ", context.log_group_name)
    print ("Request ID: ", context.aws_request_id)
    print ("Mem. limits(MB): ", context.memory_limit_in_mb)
    try:
        print ("Using waiter to waiting for object to persist through s3 service")
        waiter = s3.get_waiter('object_exists')
        waiter.wait(Bucket=source_bucket, Key=object_key)
        s3.copy(Bucket=target_bucket, Key=object_key, CopySource=copy_source)
        return response['ContentType']
    except Exception as err:
        print ("Error -"+str(err))
        return e
```

I've created a test case, howver when it runs it shows errors, whats causing these?

Test Case Json

```json
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "127.0.0.1"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "EXAMPLE123456789",
        "x-amz-id-2": "EXAMPLE123/5678abcdefghijklambdaisawesome/mnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGH"
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "testConfigRule",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "removed-backups",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "EXAMPLE"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::example-bucket"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "HappyFace.jpg",
          "size": 1024,
          "eTag": "0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef",
          "sequencer": "0A1B2C3D4E5F678901"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Log

```json
START RequestId: xxx123 Version: $LATEST
Source bucket :  removed-backups
Target bucket :  removed-backups-keep
Log Stream name:  2022/05/15/[$LATEST]removed
Log Group name:  /aws/lambda/copy-files-to-keep
Request ID:  removed
Mem. limits(MB):  128
Using waiter to waiting for object to persist through s3 service
Error -name 'response' is not defined
[ERROR] NameError: name 'e' is not defined

{
  "errorMessage": "name 'e' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "requestId": "removed",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 35, in lambda_handler\n    return e\n"
  ]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Boto3 Copy\_Object failing on size > 5GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52879356/boto3-copy-object-failing-on-size-5gb)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I've made the change, and hopefully next time the backup runs it will copy the 5GB file. Will provide an update in a few days!

Comment: The issue still persists, I made the change as suggested, but the large file isn't being coppied. Is there a way to debug and test it manually?

Comment: I've updated my original post, getting errors reported with my test case.

Comment: what did you change in the code above? it looks like it's still using the copy_object method, which is incorrect as per the post linked by @OARP

Comment: Sorry I didn't update that in my original post, it's now done. Replaced "s3.copy_object" with "s3.copy"

Comment: I've updated my original question, appreciate any assistance.