# Copy Files from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket using event notification

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

I need to copy files from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket using event notification ( so file should be copied as soon as it is created in first bucket).

I am planning to use AWS Lambda ( Python) and write code in Lambda to copy files. But I am afraid for large file copy time taken might be greater than 15 minutes. Also, if for some reason Lambda fails, we lose the event.

is there a better way for this? may be somehow use SQS queue and trigger some other copy function using this queue? Please advise best approach.

Comment: Why not use S3 replication? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-how-setup.html

Comment: I might delete the objects from first bucket once it is copied to second bucket. Can I still use S3 replication?

Comment: By default deleting in the source bucket does not delete from the target bucket. You have to enable an extra feature to get the deletes to replicate https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/delete-marker-replication.html

Comment: You mentioned a concern about losing the event, so see [Failure handling between S3 trigger and Lambda](https://repost.aws/questions/QUADGtXlR5SECXdKFQairNqA/failure-handling-between-s-3-trigger-and-lambda). You might want to test what's viable in Lambda right now in terms of object size and the time it takes to move (copy/delete) an object then decide if failures are sufficiently rare that you can deal with them through a DLQ or event notification that triggers a manual process or short-duration EC2-based process. Also be aware of S3 Batch.

Comment: S3 Replication is certainly the best option. If you do use Lambda, then please note that copying objects between S3 buckets can be very fast -- it does not involve downloading then re-uploading the data. If you have large objects, then make sure your code can take advantage of Multi-part Uploads: [Boto3 Copy_Object failing on size > 5GB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52883426/174777)

Comment: For sample code, see: [Requirement is transfer of files between s3 buckets through lambda, taking keys of source s3 file dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62407236/174777)

Comment: @MarkB I need to add some additional functionality. For ex: I need to rename the files during copy to destination bucket ( change testfile from source bucket to testfile_30Jan2023 in destination etc.) which I think can not be done using S3 replication. this is why I am trying to use Lambda function to copy files.

Comment: So use an SQS queue then. And if the copies are taking longer than 15 minutes, use ECS instead of Lambda.

Comment: @MarkB can you please explain in little bit more details. how/what to do with ECS? I have not used this service before.